# PyDev can autocomplete inherited method names but not field names

Tags: django, pydev

So i'm into django quickstart tutorial, and i'm currently using the latest pydev on the eclipse version of 2019-03 (4.11.0). Here's a code snippet:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

I tried navigating (F3) on generic.DetailView, and it works fine. I tried typing `def [ctrl+space]` and i can see what methods to override, including get_queryset.

What i dont get is when i tried to `ctrl+space` on the field section in hope to see `template_name` or `context_object_name` but cannot find them, even after i tried narrowing them by typing the field name.

Navigating to parent types work, and pydev can also see inherited methods, but why not the inherited fields ?

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally typed F4, and it showed the hierarchy of the class focused by the cursor. And this is good enough although ctrl T doesnt work like java. Hope this helps.